# El fondo de página no aparece cuando subo la página a un alojamiento web

Tags: html, css

Estoy desarrollando una página web y en mi computadora local se ven excelentes las páginas, pero al subirlas a un alojamiento web solo se ve la imagen de fondo en la página principal, en las demás páginas aparecen con un fondo blanco.

Revisé las direcciones y está todo perfecto, no entiendo por qué pasa esto.

El `background` y el `body` los tengo así y funcionan perfecto cuando los miro en mi PC sin subirlos:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{ 
  background-image:url(../../Imagenes/DukiGeneral.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size:  cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

---

Revise las direcciones, mayusculas y minusculas pero no encuentro respuesta, en mi pc desde el host se ve perfecto el background pero al entrar a mi web desde el movil veo el fondo blanco y luego el contenido de la pagina se ve perfecto pero el problema es el fondo, lo que me resulta raro es que en mi movil la pagina principal si funciona con background pero las subdirecciones que les comento no, cabe recalcar que en estas paginas tengo funcionando el carousel de bootstrap, tendra algo que ver?, otra cosa para agregar es que esto sucede desde el navegador de google chrome, en el navegador por defecto de mi movil si se puede apreciar el background

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador y comprueba que te está cogiendo correctamente las imágenes, porque la verdad es que parece un problema de direcciones.

Comment: Debés verificar que hayas subido la imágen y verificar que la dirección esté correcta. <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-html --> ../../Imagenes/DukiGeneral.jpg <!-- end snippet -->

Comment: seguramente sea la ruta, si lo tienes en localhost, y luego lo subes a un host público, ya no tendrá la misma ruta , con el inspector de elementos puedes revisar a dónde está intentando coger la imagen y si corresponde con la URL correcta

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitarnos la URL para comprobar el problema? ¿Has comprobado que las mayúsculas y minúsculas coincida exactamente? Te en cuenta que en Windows puedes usar cualquier combinación y te funcionará, pero en la gran mayoría de alojamientos no porque están basados en sistemas operativos UN*X. ¿Esos estilos están insertados en cada HTML o forman parte de un archivo CSS separado? ¿Podrías incluir el nombre de las páginas HTML y del archivo CSS si procede? Gracias.

Comment: Recuerda que la ruta es relativa al fichero desde donde se carga dicha configuración CSS. Si descartas errores en las rutas... Otra cosa que puedes revisar es que los los ficheros y carpetas no tengan nombres con espacios ni signos de puntuación. Esto puede dar problemas con la codificación de caracteres al cambiar de servidor. También te puedes encontrar diferencias en cuanto al uso de mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Gonzalo. ¿Podrías compartirnos el HTML completo o algún sitio donde poder comprobar el conjunto de tu página para poder determinar el problema? Únicamente con lo que nos proporcionas no podemos hacer nada. Gracias.